# How can I pass N number of generic arguments to a typedef function pointer?

Tags: c++, generics, typedef

I have this typedef function pointer ***plot***:

```
typedef void(*plot)();
```

How can I pass a generic argument to it (Something like this):

```
template<typename T>
typedef void(*plot)(T);
```

And then, how can I pass N number of generic arguments to it?

```
template<typename T>
typedef void(*plot)(T ...);
```

Comment: You don't "pass generic arguments" in C++; you instantiate template functions and then you invoke them. You need to elaborate on what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: If you use something better than a function pointer, then a lambda or `std::bind` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11, you can do something like this

```
template<typename T>
using fun_ptr = void (*)(T);
```

And for the second case,

```
template<typename... T>
using fun_ptr = void (*)(T ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using a combination of [Variadic Templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) and [Type Aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) as follows:

```
template<typename... T>
using ptr = void (*)(T ...);
```

Example:

```
template<typename... T>
using ptr = void (*)(T ...);

void f(int n, string s, float x)
{
    cout << n << s << x;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ptr<int, string, float> x; // Arbitrary number of template arguments of arbitrary types.
    x = f;
    x(7, " nasty function pointer ", 3.4);

    return 0;
}
```

Observation: If the ellipsis is omitted after the typename, like so:

```
template<typename T>
using ptr = void (*)(T ...);
```

The compiler raises a "wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 1)" error, considering the aforementioned example.